# Loaded with wrong encoding. Convert it back.

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a code parsing a website. The website is iso-8859-1 but the site is loaded another place outside my part of the code(used to load multiple sites). When the site is loaded the code spesifies that it is utf8. Which is wrong.

So when I do parse the site, no special characters work. They just showing alot of questionmark (?). Is it possible to convert it back to iso-8859-1. Feel like I have tried everything.

Comment: You can always guess what the question marks should be. Other than that, no.

Comment: Probably yes.  .  A char/string consists of two byte objects with a private property that indicates that the char is one or two bytes.  The good thing about utf8 encoding is it doesn't alter the data.  It just convert a byte[] to a string with each character set to one byte.So converting back to a byte array using encoding and then using the correct iso-8859-1 should work.

Comment: @jdweng: du you have an examplecode doing that? I have no clue.

Comment: It is only 3 characters. Æøå. So if it it possible to recognize which questionmark is what, I could replace them maybe.

Comment: string input = "enter your bad string here";
            byte[] myBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

            System.Text.Encoding iso_8859_1 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

            string output = iso_8859_1.GetString(myBytes);

Comment: Thank. I will try that tonight.

Comment: This was working like a charm. Thank you again.